# Spacy Version Error in Android using Chaquopy and nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") Error

Tags: python, android, chaquopy, spacy-3

I am using spacy (nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") in my code while using chaquopy but give error of version not compatible because chaquopy prefer native wheel is the any soloution so can fix this problem
the images of error message are given below
[In this image we have spacy version problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGJW.png)

[This picture show that the spacy is downloaded but chaquopy download previous version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR9oe.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spacy version 2.2.3, then the compatible versions of en_core_web_sm are probably the ones starting with "2.2". To find them:

- Go to https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models.
- Click the "master" button at the top left, then click "Tags".
- In the search box above "Tags", type "en_core_web_sm".

This shows that the available 2.2 versions are 2.2.0 and 2.2.5. So try changing both version numbers in the spacy-models URL to one of those.

Older versions are only available in .tar.gz format, not .whl, so the URL should be `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/MODEL_VERSION/MODEL_VERSION.tar.gz`, where `MODEL_VERSION` is something like `en_core_web_sm-2.2.5`. You can pass that URL directly to the [`install` command](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#requirements) in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Hello, is there any chance Chaqoupy will support Spacy version> = 2.3? I found Polish models only from this version and they do not currently work in Chaquopy.

Comment: Chaquopy is now open-source, so you can try building a new Spacy version yourself. You can find the build tool in [this repository](https://github.com/chaquo/build-wheel).